# Polars: how to add a column in front?

Tags: python-polars

What would be the most idiomatic (and efficient) way to add a column in front of a polars data frame? Same thing like `.with_column` but add it at index 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `select` in the order you want your new `DataFrame`.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, 3],
    "b": [True, None, False]
})

df.select([
    pl.lit("foo").alias("z"),
    pl.all()
])
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬───────┐
│ z   ┆ a   ┆ b     │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ bool  │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ foo ┆ 1   ┆ true  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ foo ┆ 2   ┆ null  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ foo ┆ 3   ┆ false │
└─────┴─────┴───────┘
```